# Find file with largest number of lines in single directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to create a function that only outputs the file with the largest number of lines in a directory (and not any sub-directories). I'm being asked to make use of the `wc` function but don't really understand how to read each file individually and then sort them just to find the largest. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

function sort {
[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "Invalid number of arguments">&2 && exit 1;
[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "Invalid input: not a directory">&2 && exit 1;
# Insert function here ; 
}

# prompt if wanting current directory
# if yes
    # sort $PWD
    # if no
        #sort $directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is almost pure Bash (`wc` is the only external command used):

```
shopt -s dotglob    # Include filenames with initial '.' in globs
shopt -s nullglob   # Make globs produce nothing when nothing matches

dir=$1

maxlines=-1
maxfile=

for file in "$dir"/* ; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue      # Skip non-files
    [[ -L $file ]] && continue      # Skip symlinks

    numlines=$(wc -l < "$file")

    if (( numlines > maxlines )) ; then
        maxfile=$file
        maxlines=$numlines
    fi
done

[[ -n "$maxfile" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$maxfile"
```

Remove the `shopt -s dotglob` if you don't want to process files whose names begin with a dot.  Remove the `[[ -L $file ]] && continue` if you want to process symlinks to files.

This solution should handle all filenames (ones containing spaces, ones containing glob characters, ones beginning with '-', ones containing newlines, ...), but it runs `wc` for each file so it may be unacceptably slow compared to solutions that feed many files to `wc` at once if you need to handle directories that have large numbers of files.

Comment: @NicholasNorris, thanks for the comment.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
wc -l * | sort -nr | head -2 | tail -1
```

`wc -l` counts lines (you get an error for directories, though), then sort in reverse order treating the first column as a number, then take the first two lines, then the second, as we need to skip over the `total` line.

```
wc -l * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -2 | tail -1
```

The `2>/dev/null` throws away all the errors, if you want a neater output.

Comment: How do I send the directory I need it in as an argument. I tried `wc -l $1/*` but the validation is telling me it's not a directory and then the 'wc' command is telling me it is a directory...

Comment: Hmm, not sure - what does `echo $1/*` say? Does your directory have a space character within it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this:

```
my_custom_sort() {
   for i in "${1+$1/}"*; do 
     [[ -f "$i" ]] && wc -l "$i"
   done | sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -d" " -f2
}
```

And use it with or without directory (in latter case, it uses the current directory):

```
my_custom_sort /tmp
helloworld.txt
```